# Why is this possible in Java: this.getClass().getClass().getClass()....etc

Tags: java, class

Why is this possible in Java:

```
this.getClass().getClass().getClass().getClass()...
```

Why is there this infinite recursion?

Just curious.

Comment: Infinite? Not quite. `Object#getClass()`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Class is Object itself, so yes, quite infinite

Comment: Because Class is a subclass of Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Class` object is still an object, and you can call `getClass` on any object, thanks to the existence of `Object#getClass`. So you get:

```
this.getClass(); // Class<YourClass>
this.getClass().getClass(); // Class<Class<YourClass>>
this.getClass().getClass().getClass(); //Class<Class<Class<YourClass>>>
```

Eventually you'll run out of stack memory, time, or disk space for such a huge program, or reach a Java internal limit.

Comment: You confuse recursion with identity operation.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Edited about 10 seconds ago,

Comment: @hexafraction Yeah, the edit popped up just as I entered my comment. I'll delete!

Comment: @Ingo Not identity, what of generic parameters?

Comment: Yes right, the types are different. Anyway, one cannot call a finite number of chained method calls "infinite recursion". Thnakfully, you removed it.

Answer (score 10):

There's no infinite recursion here: `getClass()` returns a `java.lang.Class` object, which is itself a `java.lang.Object` object, hence it supports `getClass()` method. After the second call to `getClass()` you are going to get the same result, no matter how many times you call `getClass()`.

Comment: What is the upper limit on the number of methods that can be chained? Surely there has to be some limit, may be limited by stacksize, or some other factor?

Comment: @RohitJain I do not think the stack is involved here at all: the compiler does all the work by "unrolling" the chain of calls, preparing the call target for the following call by invoking the prior one, and storing the reference.

Comment: Ah! I missed it. So this will run until Memory blows out, and will eventually end with an OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: @RohitJain Not even that: there's no new memory needed for it either. The only limitation here is the OS-dictated size of the source file, and JVM-dictated size of a single class. The `java.lang.Class` object will always be the same, so no new allocation would be necessary.

Comment: @RohitJain - there is a limit on the size of the bytecode array for a single method.  The compiler will let you know if you exceed it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I guess JVM limits the size of the method. So, I guess that would limit the level of invocation. I'm seraching through the JVM specs to get the exact limitation.

Comment: From this section - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4 it seems like the limit is based on the available memory.

Comment: The limit is a given by the code_length field of the Code attribute; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3.  (It is a `u4` ... so the limit is 2^32 bytes ... in theory.)

Comment: I would call it recursion, because the Class class calls getClass() on itself over and over again...basically, right

Comment: @AlexMills Yet it always calls it on a different object. `Class<Class<Class>>` is not the same as `Class<Class>`.

Comment: @AlexMills It's not `getClass` that performs the call, it's the caller of `getClass`. The chain of calls can be described recursively, but in the text of the program it is not even a nesting going on.

Comment: @hexafraction I am pretty sure that this is not what happens: once you hit `getClass` of the `Class` object, ["it's turtles all the way down"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down) from there on ([demo](http://ideone.com/M5cQ01)).

Comment: @StephenC Actually wouldn't the limit here be the maximum length of the bytecode a method can contain (64kb iirc)? Edit: yes it is, here (4.9.1): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9

Answer (score 2):

Every class extends the `Object` class. `Class` being a class itself it inheritates the `getClass()` method. Allowing you to call `Class#getClass().getClass()` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

That's not recursion.

Recursion is where a method calls itself (defining loosely) for a finite number of times before it finally returns.

For example:

```
public int sumUpTo(int i) {
    if (i == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return i + sumUpTo(i-1);
    }
}
```

What you have done is call a method to get this object's class and then getting the class of the class (`java.lang.Class`) and repeating it for as long as you care to type.

Answer (score 1):

```
public final Class<? extends Object> getClass()
```

getClass() returns a Class object. Since Class is a derivative of Object, it too has a getClass method. You should print a few iterations. You should notice a repeating pattern after the first call...